# Need some update on Barcode activity with .NET (C#) for web application

Tags: .net, barcode

Need some update on Barcode activity with .NET (C#) for web application. Requirement is to generate a Barcode (based on patient id), get it printed on patient vising card & read the barcode from the given card. Thus, need the help in doing with any sample code, link, available free component, etc. Thanks for the support, in advance.

Comment: Have you seen this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437612/can-anyone-recommend-an-open-source-net-component-to-make-barcodes?rq=1